# Using Purrr or Furrr to filter, and pass character vectors into additional functions

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, furrr

I have some very inefficient code that I am hoping someone can help me with.  I don't have a great reprex, but have created a sample of the current code/workflow I'm using.

Here's what I'm trying to do concisely

- Filter dataset into groups
- Pass filtered datasets into 3 separate functions (Feature Selection, Validation, and Application)

The groups(filtered) are consistent from feature selection to validation to application.
Workflow is:

1. Feature Selection takes filtered data and returns a character vector of features for each group
2. Validation takes 2 arguments: Filtered data by group, and the character vector result corresponding to that group that came out of 1(Feature Selection).  Return `df` for each group and select only the columns `prediction` and `linear_weight`.  Then row bind
3. Application takes the same 2 arguments as 2(Validation).  Return `df` for each group and select columns based on features that exist in every group (from 1), `prediction` and `linear_weight`.  Then row bind

I have no doubt that some version of `purrr` could likely make my code much more efficient & improve the run time dramatically.  One idea I had would be to save the results of the select features into a `df` with the features residing in a column, and pass that column result to the `validate_data` and `applicate_data` functions.

Apologies for not having something fully reproducible.  Hopefully this example gives a good idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
library(gapminder)

data <- gapminder_unfiltered

# Filter data
group_1_data <- gapminder_unfiltered %>% 
  filter(country %in% c("Algeria", "Benin"))

group_2_data <- gapminder_unfiltered %>% 
  filter(country == "United States")

group_3_data <- gapminder_unfiltered %>% 
  filter(country %in% c("Italy", "France"))


# Feature Selection
group_1_features <- select_features(group_1_data)
group_2_features <- select_features(group_2_data)
group_3_features <- select_features(group_3_data)

# Example of group_1_features output
c("pop", "gdpPercap")

# Validation
group_1_validation <- validate_data(group_1_data, group_1_features)
group_2_validation <- validate_data(group_2_data, group_2_features)
group_3_validation <- validate_data(group_3_data, group_3_features)

# Row bind Validations selecting only created columns of "prediction" & "linear_weight"
all_validations

# Application: Same Inputs as Validation
group_1_application <- applicate_data(group_1_data, group_1_features)
group_2_application <- applicate_data(group_2_data, group_2_features)
group_3_application <- applicate_data(group_3_data, group_3_features)

# Row bind applications.  Select columns/features that exist in every group based on the feature selection.  Also select columns "prediction" & "linear_weight"
total_applications
```

Answer (score 0):

purrr::map can be used since there are three data frames stored in a list, and then you can Reduce the result to rbind it all together.

```
library(dplyr)

groups_data=list(group_1_data, group_2_data, group_3_data)

select_features=function(d) {
  features=c()
  if (sample(c(0,1), 1)==0) {
    features=c("pop", "gdpPercap")
  } else {
    features=c("pop", "gdpPercap", "lifeExp")
  }
  return(list(d,
              features))
}

features_list=purrr::map(groups_data, select_features)

validate_data=function(feat_list) {
  d=feat_list[[1]]
  ret=mutate(d, prediction=rnorm(nrow(d)), linear_weight=runif(nrow(d)))
  return (ret)
}

val_list=purrr::map(features_list, validate_data)

Reduce(function(x, y) {
  return(rbind(x, select(y, prediction, linear_weight))) 
}, val_list[2:3], init=select(val_list[[1]], prediction, linear_weight))

applicate_data=function(feat_list) {
  d=feat_list[[1]]
  ret=mutate(d, prediction=rnorm(nrow(d)), linear_weight=runif(nrow(d)))
  return (ret)
}

appl_list=purrr::map(features_list, applicate_data)

Reduce(function(x, y) {
  return(rbind(x, select(y, prediction, linear_weight))) 
}, appl_list[2:3], init=select(appl_list[[1]], prediction, linear_weight))
```

Comment: I have a function that I created that selects the features.  I'm trying to figure out how to pass the features results by group to the other 2 functions, and return df according to the columns I outlined.

Comment: Use purrr::map?